# In MySQL is this possible to query the database in specify time using SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For example, the data is like this:

`[id][name]`

at 10:00, the data is like this:

`[1][John]`

at 11:00, the user edit the data change to this:

`[1][Johnson]`

So, user use the alter command to change the data, but it is possible for the database query back the data on 10:00 in MySQL? Thanks.

Comment: Consider using crontabs, I guess. It takes away the pain.

Comment: What about using of a trigger after update?

Comment: not easily, time machine or low level analysis of the disk. You could extend your schema to have a `version` and `timestamp` column, that would make it easier.

Comment: @IgorLozovsky, the trigger would have to store the history elsewhere but potentially yes.

Comment: This is called Point in Time Architecture and is a w-i-d-e-l-y discussed topic - both in the context of RDBMs generally and MySQL in particular.

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about is versioning. Having time stamp and version number would help but storing multiple records in same table with same id would cause a decrease in data integrity - what about a trigger on the table and insert into some form of audit table?

Answer (score 0):

In general you have two options:

1. Add a colum version with a timestamp and expand the primary key to your currient PK and the version. To grep the data you just need to select the least version e.g. with max. Or add another colum with a bit value for the newest version. This should be faster to select.
2. Create a table with historical values. To implement this you need to add a trigger to the orginal table on update and copy the old value in your history table. So you can see all changes.